# Trying to generalize this script

Tags: powershell, nas

I have written the following PS script:

```
cmdkey /add:pcname /user:network\username /pass:password
New-PSDrive -Name "E" -Root "\\vm-beta\ShareOne" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"
```

This will save the given NAS user's login credentials in windows Credential Manager and then map the given network share in windows file explorer as a local drive

My problem is this isn't generic enough. I'm trying to generalize this script in that once the given user's login credentials - for the NAS - are typed into and saved in the Credential Manager, the rest of the script will get all the network shares - on the NAS - the given user has access to  and map every one of them in windows File Explorer as a local drive.

For this purpose so far I've written this script that isn't working:

```
# Prompt user for NAS credentials and save in Credential Manager
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter NAS Login Credentials"
cmdkey /add:NAS /user:$($credential.Username) /pass:$($credential.Password)

# Get all network shares accessible to the given user on the NAS
$networkShares = Get-SmbShare -CimSession NAS -Credential $credential

# Map all network shares as drives in Windows File Explorer
foreach ($share in $networkShares) {
    New-PSDrive -Name $share.Name -Root $share.Path -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $credential
}
```

How can I create that script? I've been trying to fix this for hours

above is what im trying to do

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I would recommend

- Use GPO to manage file shares
- Look into potentially using `File Share Conditional Access`
  - Users with no access to a share will not be able to see a shared folder
  - Reduces the amount of GPO's you have to manage and allows you to just share `\\NAS\FileShares` instead of having to scope it to a department `\\NAS\FileShares\Dept1`

Comment: @albvar  I don't have a domain controller nor do I have any GPO active. This is not an AD network. The point of my post is that I'm trying to get the script to work. once it works, I'll inject it into the image with NTLite so it'll run automatically once the user has logged on for the first time post-deployment of the image

Comment: In that case, `Get-SmbShare` does not support a -Credential parameter but does support -CimSession. You can specify the credential inside of your CimSession. This credential must be an Administrator on your NAS server. Is this the case?

Comment: @albvar I am the only NAS Admin and I'm trying to create this script for standard users that only have read access (no write access) to some of the network shares on the NAS

Comment: You've still not explained what isn't working in your script. Virtually nobody is going to have a spare NAS on a non-windows domain to test things out for you. How are you creating a CIMSESSION to use in the `-CimSession` parameter?

Comment: @Scepticalist you're right. Can you help me make the script work? Forget the CimSession route, I've abandoned it.

Comment: Ditch `Get-SmbShare` this won't work on a NAS device. This cmdlet requires a windows based File Share Server. You are better off just prompting for credentials and mapping a list of known file shares with those credentials.

Comment: albvar So you're saying I should just stick with my original script then?                                         Because the problem is that there's a whole lot of different users with different network share accesses so I'd have to change the script with different pw/username and network shares. Also, I wanna inject this script into the image with NTLite (running automatically post-installation as MACHINE not USER) and in this case I'd have to create 5-6 different ISO system images

Comment: The very first comment asks what error you're getting. It's the only thing you haven't responded to.

Comment: Yes stick to original script, `Get-SMBShare` won't work in a non-windows ecosystem. If your NAS is a non-windows system then you can not rely on this approach. @JustinBeagley - no point in asking what the original error is, simply NAS is not running windows and Get-SMBShare simply won't work there.